Replacing value by matching it to unique ID if criteria is met
Edit: sorry i should have mentioned, there is only excel 2019 version.
I have added some dummy data below. Basically, I want to replace the value in a new column if it says "Self Employed" with the respective company it is tagged to of the same ID number. Else, remain the same name. Anybody can help me with this?

I have this formula currently
=IF(B2="Self-Employed", VLOOKUP(A2, A:B, 2, FALSE), B2)
But it does not always replace. Sometimes but it only replaces the value if the row with the company names comes first, and not when "Self Employed comes first". I have thousands of rows to do so any method other than manually replacing will be apreciated

Perhaps =IF(B2="Self-Employed", VLOOKUP(A2, FILTER(A:B,B="Self-Employed"), 2, FALSE), B2)

=LOOKUP(1,($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7<>"Self Employed"),$B$2:$B$7) requires entering with ctrl+shift+enter in older Excel versions.

@nkalvi I believe from the very minimal example the idea is to find the company name with the same ID for any Self Eployed values. Then it should contain at least one combination of that ID with the company name.

With CHOOSECOLS, FILTER and TOCOL functions
Formula in cell C25 and drag down
=IF(B25="self",TAKE(TOCOL(IF(CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(A$25:B$30,A$25:A$30=A25),2)<>"self",FILTER(B$25:B$30,A$25:A$30=A25),1/0),2),1),B25)

TOCOL filters out rows with other ID's.
TAKE return one Company value to avoid SPILL error.

thank you for your help, unfortunately I just realise I have the old excel version and do not have formulas such as TAKE, TOCOL, FILTER and such. My apologies and appreciate your help further if you have any workaround!
